# Is Deep Class Hierarchies to solve version good?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a abstract class `BaseClass` and extend class `Class1` `Class2` `Class3` `Class...`
All the class has **version** concept.
The class hint is this

```
internal abstract class BaseClass
{
  internal abstract bool MethodA();
  internal abstract bool MethodB();
  ...
}
```

```
// you can imagine Class1 is version 1
internal class Class1 : BaseClass
{
  internal override bool MethodA() => ...; // do something belong Class1 version logic
  internal override bool MethodB() => ...; // do something belong Class1 version logic
  ...
}
```

Now, I have a problem with this.
When I want to upgrade my business logic to version 2,but the inner logic is half the same.
Is't used inherit possibled a good idea?

```
// you can imagine Class2 is version 2
internal class Class2 : Class1
{
  // the MethodA is the same with Class1, so the place didn't override
  internal override bool MethodB() => ...; // new logic different than Class1.MethodB
  ...
}
```

Have this problem because I think when n years after. This class is possible upgrade to version n,so that the inherit will be very deep.

```
// ex:
Class3 : Class2;
Class4 : Class3;
Class5 : Class4;
...
```

Or anyone have idea to solve the version issue?(Again, that have 90% the same and 10% different in each iterate)

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't place tags in your question title. We already have the tagging system that you've already used for your question. There's no need to reiterate that yes, you are in fact using C# and .NET - we already know.

Comment: Why would you want to keep versions of the business logic? Following you're example MethodB from Class2 overrides old business logic, why not modify the original business logic in Class1?

Comment: It seems quite odd to keep extended your classes like this. What's the purpose?

Comment: Another solution is to define interface(s) for your business logic then implement these interfaces in classes in an assembly project with version 1.0.0
Later when you change one or more method implementations you simply change the code in your project and increase the version to 1.1 e.g.
So now you have assembly with business logic 1.0 and another separate assembly with business logic 1.1 and so on

Comment: @3dd We have old case issue,so that the old version case should used old version logic. And that will both(or more than two version) run on production environment in business at the same time.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama thanks! sorry about that this is my first post.

Comment: @Enigmativity because in my business logic the new version and old version will both(or more than two version) run together, and different version case should run as belong version logic

Comment: @as860215 - I think you'd be better off with composition rather than inheritance. Much easier to work with, reason against, and refactor.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah..composition is one of my solution. But I'm thinking what composition and inheritance respective advantages.

Comment: @as860215 - When you compose you can pick and choose behaviour. Inheritance locks it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take step back and implement in most straight forward way:

```
public class Class1 : BaseClass
{ 
  public void MethodA() {...}
  public void MethodB() {...}
}

public class Class2 : BaseClass
{ 
  public void MethodA() {/* same as in Class1 */}
  public void MethodB() {...}
}
```

and now you want to avoid this code duplication.

So I would suggest going in direction of composition and define Class2 as wrapper around Class1 and continue this approach outwards:

```
public class Class2 : BaseClass
{ 
  private readonly BaseClass prevVersionClass;

  public Class2(BaseClass prevVersionClass)
  {
    this.prevVersionClass = prevVersionClass;
  }

  public void MethodA() { prevVersionClass.MethodA(); }
  public void MethodB() {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
This direction is one of my original solution.
But when I want to implement, I think about this inherit solution.
I have no idea which better in both solution.

Comment: @as860215 Generally compoisition is better than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply prefer composition over inheritance and used an appropriate design pattern for versioning.

If you want to stick to inheritance, then it is fine. Code duplication cant exist, you can do the following:

1. Create new functions that the derived class will inherit but not override.
2. Use the Open-Closed principle (part of SOLID), and let the client side deliver the logic through a delegate.
3. Segregate concerns further and use dependency injection in the relevant classes that you concern may have duplicate code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
The DI is not my solution is that. 
In my business logic, all the different version case will used in the same time(even if that have 10+ version). Means I should coexistence of old and new.